# karma jasmine and angular ng-cookies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have written a test for my application but get the following error from ng-cookies:

```
 TypeError: $browser.addPollFn is not a function in static/js/angular/ng-cookies_1.3.13.js (line 60)
```

I googled and found that the version of ng-cookies must match the version of angular which is does. Here my karma config:

```
files: [
    'static/js/jquery-1.11.2.js'
    ,'static/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js'
    ,'static/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ,'static/js/angular/angular_1.3.13.js'
    ,'static/js/angular/ng-cookies_1.3.13.js'
    ,'static/js/angular/angular-common-libs.min.js'
    ,'static/js/angular/angular-ui-sortable.js'
    ,'static/js/angular/angular-route.min_1.3.13.js'
```

I though that would fix it or the order that it is being loaded but it made no difference.

This is the app.js initialisation that calls the ng-cookies:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[ 
    'ui.router'
    , 'ui.bootstrap'
            , 'ui.sortable'
    , 'fileUpload'
    , 'angular-loading-bar'
    , 'ncy-angular-breadcrumb'
    , 'ngSanitize'
    , 'ngMessages'
    , 'ngCookies'
```

**What am I missing?  Is karma loading a different version of angular somewhere I would presume the one I specified in the files array is the correct one?**

Comment: What about angular-mocks and its version? It overrides $browser.

Comment: @estus  yes that was the problem I will put it as an answer to help others, nice one thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @estus providing the correct answer. I needed the correct version of the angular-mocks, that fixed it.